# Why the default constructor is not provided when typing an argument-ed constructor in java?

Tags: java, oop

In java, if we type an argument-ed constructor for a class, we cannot call it's default parameter less constructor. I know that is because of the compiler not providing the default parameter less constructor if we type any argument-ed constructor. But my question is what is the reason to design it like this?

Comment: Why does Java provide a default constructor at all? [Answer: It's a cock-up.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide a constructor with arguments it's assumed the object will be created with valid state.

If a no-arg constructor was exposed by default (and the class's creator didn't take defensive action), it would be possible for someone to inadvertently create an invalid object--an object without enough information to be correct.

By forcing us to provide a no-arg constructor, Java forces us to explicitly communicate that it's okay to create an object *without* those initial values/state.

Nutshell: Java is attempting to save us from ourselves, because we are sloppy and forgetful.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. So, it's about the initial state.

Comment: @NamalFernando Well, maybe not initial state, but communication, and preventing unintended behavior. Preventing *unintentional* bogus initial state due to skipping over required constructor params was one thing that was easy to eliminate, so they did.

Comment: @ Dave : Thanks again for the explanation Dave, Got your point.

Answer (score 1):

It is to enable class designers to forbid using a non-argument constructor.

This can be for various reasons, e.g. the class has some members initialized though constructor arguments, so in the functions, the class can safely assume these members to be not null.

If the default constructor is still available, every function should check if this member is null or not.

Comment: You could do that anyway by making it private.

Comment: Thanks greyfaire. but I also agree with Dave.

Comment: I think it was a compromise design decision between forcing to write a default constructor when you want one (as in C++) or forcing to explicitly making it private when you don't want one.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't provide a constructor, it assumes you need one and creates one for you.

When you provide a constructor it assumes you know what you are doing and that you will be providing every constructor you really want. This is to prevent creation of a default constructor which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done: the compiler could see there is no default constructor but there is a (T...) constructor, and create one:

```
...() { this(new T[0]); }
```

Either it was forgotten or thought ugly. What when there is a (U...)?

Comment: @ Joop : Yep, you can allow to call the parameter-less constructor when you typed an argument-ed constructor by EXPLICITLY TYPE A PARAMETERLESS CONSTRUCTOR. That is true. But my question was why it is not allowed to call it BY DEFAULT(without explicitly typing it) when you typed an argument-ed constructor?

Comment: @Namal Fernando : if there is only one constructor with just varargs, it would be logical that () would call that one. Seems an oversight. The call of <init>() is still probably searching a declaration with no parameters. Where it also should look whether there exists exactly one constructor with varargs only param.